# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'device'

Tags: python, pytorch

При выполнении кода из официальной документации silero происходит следующая ошибка:

```
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'device'
```

Выдающий ошибку код:

```
# V3
import torch

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'v3_1_ru'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'xenia'
device = torch.device('cpu')

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                 model='silero_tts',
                                 language=language,
                                 speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)  # gpu or cpu

audio = model.apply_tts(text=example_text,
                    speaker=speaker,
                    sample_rate=sample_rate)
```

При этом библиотека pytorch **актуальной версии (1.11.0)** была установлена через анаконду командой с [официального сайта](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

Пожалуйста подскажите как решить проблему,

Comment: Как называется файл с вашим кодом?

Comment: как называется файл?

Comment: Файл с кодом называется Source.py